# Why is this terminology question not well received in programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion

Refer to this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/250477/91517) which I've wrote yesterday.

I don't have much experience with packages terminology, so I've put my best effort into constructing a scenario to illustrate a real and simple use case, then asked what terminology should be used for it.

As far as I can see, if there is no proper terminology then the answer should be just that – "there is no standard terminology that meets your criteria".

Yet, my question was downvoted and closed as primarily opinion based.

Looking through meta, all I could find was [Why is this terminology question considered as “opinion based”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/why-is-this-terminology-question-considered-as-opinion-based) whose accepted answer supports my point.

So, is there anything I can improve in my question, or is it just not welcome here for some other reason?

Comment: Thanks @gnat, that does shed some light for me. I didn't know about the ELU issues with single word requests either, thanks for that as well.

Comment: Gnat's link is enough to answer this meta question, I'll flag as dupe as well. I've updated my terminology [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/250477/91517) in regards to the points listed in the linked dupe, mostly to just don't leave it without an answer.