# Why was this question directly closed as primarily opinion based and directly removed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, deleted-questions

I have recently asked [Is there a short term to describe long technical terms abbreviations?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392353/is-there-a-short-term-to-describe-long-technical-terms-abbreviations?noredirect=1#comment863912_392353) which is related to software development terms such as i18n.

I have quickly got an answer that pointed to [the exact answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym):

> Alternatively, the letters between the first and last are replaced
>   with a number representing the number of letters omitted, **such as
>   "i18n" for "internationalization"**. Sometimes the last letter is also
>   counted and omitted. These word shortenings are sometimes called
>   **alphanumeric acronyms**, **alphanumeric abbreviations**, or **numerical contractions**.

I have initially thought of asking this on English, but these term seem to technical that software engineering seems more appropriate.

I can understand if this was considered offtopic for some other reason, but it is clearly not opinion based.

Related meta question: [Why is this terminology question considered as “opinion based”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/why-is-this-terminology-question-considered-as-opinion-based)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my question so quickly deleted by a moderator?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-was-my-question-so-quickly-deleted-by-a-moderator) "We have no obligation to keep your question around if it doesn't meet our community's standards. That's how it works here. Next time, you should read a site's rules and standards before posting your question."

Comment: The short answer is that your question isn't about software engineering.  There's a range of questions related to things a software engineer may encounter, but those questions aren't necessarily about software engineering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is about software engineering. Not about things that a programmer might find interesting.

Your question was about the English language, not about software engineering.

It was therefore correct to close and delete the question. It doesn't matter that you found the answer to be interesting: it is off topic, it has no place here.

I believe that a Stack Exchange site works best when it has a tightly defined scope in which it can excel – but that requires removing things that fall outside of this scope. We don't have to host any “interesting” question.